# Is it possible that a theory A is not interpretable in a theory B, and B is not interpretable in A too?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Suppose ***A*** and ***B*** are first order theories(probably, the restriction to first order theory is not essential, but for simplicity).

When one theory has finite model,the question is easy.

If one has the model of less (finite)cardinality than the other (at least cardinality case),
then the one is interpretable in the other.

Then, ***A*** is interpretable in ***B***, or ***B*** is interpretable in ***A***.

However, when both theories have no finite model, the answer to the question is not obvious(at least to me).

In that case, the 2 situation are common.

1. One is interpretable in the other, but not vice versa (e.g. ***PA*** is interpretable in ***ZF***).
2. Two theories are biinterpretable (e.g. ***ZF*** and ***ZFC*** are biinterpretable).

Then, is it possible that ***A*** is *not* interpretable in ***B***, and ***B*** is *not* interpretable in ***A*** *too*?

My own answer to the question is *Yes*.
It seems that Dan Willard's self-verifying theory(***SVT***) and ***PA*** is an example of such case.
Because ***SVT*** can prove the consistency of ***PA***, then ***SVT*** is *not* interpretable in ***PA***, and ***PA***'s diagonal argument is not representable in ***SVT***, 
then ***PA*** is *not* interpretable in ***SVT***.

But, I'm not so familiar to Dan Willard's theory, so I'm not sure.

Then, is my own answer right? or are there more example of such theories?

Comment: What about much simpler theories, like $Th(\Bbb Z,<)$ and $Th(\Bbb Q,<)$? The former is not interpretable in the latter by $\omega$-categoricity. I think the converse holds, using quantifier-elimination in the language $y<x+c$ for $c\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  But, I can't understand your argument yet.   Why do ω-categoricity imply Th(Z,<) is not interpretable in Th(Q,<)? First of all, are both Th(Z,<) and Th(Q,<) ω-categorical?

Comment: There are many examples along the lines of zarathustra's comment. For example, the theory of the random graph and the theory of the rational order. The former is simple but not NIP and the latter is NIP but not simple. So neither is interpretable in the other. Or the theory of the rational order ($\omega$-categorical but unstable) and the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ (stable but not $\omega$-categorical). Given a random pair of theories, there's no reason to suspect that either should be interpretable in the other.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your comment!  Hmm, now I'm almost convinced by zarathustra and you. But, in order to understand your argument more exactly, I have to learn model theory more. I'm not familiar to κ-categoricity or stability or NIP or... Then, I appreciate for your suggestion what to learn about. Thank you!

Comment: All of these model-theoretic properties are about capturing various types of "tame" or "easy to understand" (in some sense) theories. Usually the properties are preserved under interpretation. On the other hand, you seem mostly interested in "complicated" theories, i.e. theories of arithmetic or foundational theories. These theories will basically always fail to satisfy model-theoretic "tameness" properties.

Comment: @Alex Surely, I'm especially interested in foundational theories.
But,at least here, I just wanted to know whether such pair of theories exist.
Namely,my unsuitable choice of example is just because of my lack of knowledge.

Comment: However,you've explained the relevant ideas and suggested what to learn kindly.
I appreciate for your gracious response. I'm studying the relevant area now!  Thank you!